# Alternatives for IntraWeb in Delphi?

Tags: delphi, intraweb

Are there any alternatives for IntraWeb for Delphi,
if I want to write a simple but meaningful webserver in Delphi?

Comment: You have a strange interpretation of the WebServer concept.  Intraweb is not a WebServer... you can compile your IntraWeb application with an inside webserver, but that's not the same thing.

Comment: Could you describe in more detail what should "simple but meaningful webserver" stand for in your case?

Comment: @lightbulb & @jachgate application server for web development.

Comment: Intraweb is a framework for developing web applications using Delphi/VCL. In the IDE you design and code using Delphi language and components. Intraweb's engine generates HTML pages using JavaScript/Ajax and those pages look and behave more or less like Delphi forms and components, but in the browser context. An Intraweb application is deployed using a webServer of some sort, which serves up those pages to browser based clients.

Comment: Whoever is closing this question is not doing any good or service.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've been doing Cold Fusion, PHP and ASP work when I was also doing Delphi work, and found it strange I was writing server-side script that would get parsed over and over, while there's a really good and fast Delphi compiler! So I went out and started http://xxm.sf.net/ It provides a way to combine HTML and Object Pascal into the same files, works with IIS, Apache, Internet Explorer, FireFox, and has a plain HTTP implementation using TTcpServer also. When you make changes to the source-code (and use an AutoBuild handler) the binary is re-compiled on the fly by pressing refresh in your browser. Much like other website scripting platforms.

It's pretty crude, and new, but remember that's somewhere PHP and others were some time after they started.

Comment: Looks very good - which Delphi versions are supported?

Comment: I've only been able to use Delphi versions 6 and 7, but I've used AnsiString/WideString throughout where applicable, so it should be not too much work to make it work in a recent version, I guess... (Any help on this is welcome!)

Answer (score 3):

If you want a RIA application with Delphi, nothing is better than [uniGUI](http://www.unigui.com/).

Comment: uniGUI requires a run-time library on your server. Not desirable.

Comment: @Vector Care to explain why is that not desirable? I lack the knowledge and I'm curious. Thanks

Comment: @Petzy - if there is a  runTime libary that means you need to keep track of it when you re-deploy, if there are updates and patches to it, if you change OS versions you might run into compatibility problems, etc. In general you should try to minimize dependencies on external files and libraries - each one represents maintenance and potential problems.

Comment: @Vector Ah, gotcha, thanks for taking the time to right up a reply. Appreciate it

Answer (score 2):

Morfik tries to be RAD for web apps, was originally written in and for Delphi quite a few years ago (8 or 9), now also has versions for C# and VB.NET.  I have no experience with it, but was surprised to see a pretty well trafficked forum on their website:

Main Morfik site: http://www.morfik.com

Page with some Delphi tips: http://wiki.morfik.com/wiki3/Tips_For_Delphi_Developers

Also some components at RealThinClient that are geared towards web development with Delphi:  http://realthinclient.com/

Developer Express used to have ExpressWebFramework, which was architecturally similar to ASP.NET but was a Win32/VCL framework.  It was a competitor to IntraWeb but I don't think they sell it anymore (probably because since there's been a .NET version of Delphi the .NET web development environment has been preferred by most).

Answer (score 1):

[WebHub](http://www.href.com/webhub) is a third party alternative, as are the 2 solutions that come inbuilt into the VCL, [WebBroker](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Using_Web_Broker_Index) and [WebSnap](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Using_WebSnap_Index).

WebSnap is deprecated though so I wouldn't recommend it. WebBroker is still supported and is good at what it does, it's just it doesn't do a lot compared to say IntraWeb or WebHub.

Answer (score 0):

You can write your own web server by using Winsock unit.

Comment: You have a strange way of spelling 'NO'.